# Canvas doens't display in SAPUI5

Tags: canvas, charts, sapui5, chart.js

(Sorry if i make mistakes with my english)

I'm trying to display a graph with the library chart.js

I included it in my index.html :

```
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="app/utils/Chart.js"></script>
```

Then, i called the canvas in my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<mvc:View controllerName="Metrology.controllers.Pentagone" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
<html:canvas id="radarChart" width="800" height="650"></html:canvas>
```

And after that, i create the graph in my onBeforeRendering function of my controller :

```
onBeforeRendering : function () {

            //radar chart data
        var radarData = {
                labels : ["Performance","Security","Robustness","Changeability","Transferability",],
                datasets : [
                    {
                         fillColor: "rgba(102,45,145,.1)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : [70,70,70,70,70]
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(63,169,245,.1)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(63,169,245,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : [70,70,70,70,70]
                    }
                ]
            }
            //Create Radar chart
            var pentagone = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(pentagone).Radar(radarData);

            //new Chart(pentagone).Radar(radarData);
    }
```

And this isn't working at all. I got no error in my console, and the canvas doesn't appear at all on my application. We can select it, inspect it, but it's not even like grey or something, it's just invisible.

I tried almost everything so if you can help me guys, that would be wonderful ! :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes in your code:

1. You are calling it in event hook `onBeforeRendering`, which makes no sense because no DOM is yet rendered, i.e. element with ID `radarChart` will never be found. Move your code to event hook `onAfterReendering` instead
2. The id of your canvas will not be `radarChart` but something like `__xmlview1-radarchart` (which you could have seen upon inspecting the DOM. There would also be an error in your console, probably because method `getContext` could not be resolved)

Better use

```
<core:HTML preferDOM="true" content="&lt;canvas id='radarChart' width='800' height='650'/&gt;" />
```

instead so you can reference your canvas correctly

### EDIT:

See this working example using your code:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function(oEvent) {
    },

    onAfterRendering : function() {
        var radarData = {
            labels : ["Performance","Security","Robustness","Changeability","Transferability",],
            datasets : [
                {
                     fillColor: "rgba(102,45,145,.1)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : [70,70,70,70,70]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(63,169,245,.1)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(63,169,245,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : [70,70,70,70,70]
                }
            ]
        }
        //Create Radar chart
        var pentagone = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(pentagone, {
            type: "radar",
            data: radarData
        });
    }

});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>

<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
        <core:HTML preferDOM="true" content="&lt;canvas id='radarChart' width='800' height='650'/&gt;" />
        <Button id="myButton" change="doClick" />
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this error in my view : 
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
To the line : <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"

Comment: Check for XML well-formedness

Comment: I tried almost everything, i don't know how to remove this error. Maybe i should try to put everything in the same <script> ?

Comment: Can you post a JSBin example?

Comment: You haven't closed the `<Button>` tag properly. Since it is XML, make sure your XML is well-formatted

Comment: I came back to my original code, and now i have errors i had not before. I give up. Thanks for trying to help man

Comment: @Qualiture - you're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering.

I put everything in onAfterRendering

But my view doenst accepte

"The prefix "core" for element "core:html" is not bound."

And i'm sorry i don't know what this "DOM" things, i'm a trainee, i'm really not experimented in SAPUI5, or even in Web

Comment: The error is because most likely you haven't defined a prefix for `sap.ui.core` in your view (i.e., it's missing `xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"`). However, before deep-diving into SAPUI5, I would then recommend to learn at least the HTML/Javascript basics; codecademy.com has some great free online self-paced courses

Comment: Yes i know it would be better, but i'm trainee in a pretty big company, and they don't care about my programming skills, they just told me to make something with sapui5. I did it; but there is just that little thing wich isnt working :)